# What's a good way to make a loading UIVIew in between "presentViewController"?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am using presentViewController (for now) to get from one UIViewController to another, but when I touch the button to get to the next UIViewController, there is like a second "lag" for the first time being presented.

Anyone know an easy way to make like a "loading screen" that runs for X amount of time and THEN the desired ViewController will be presented? This way that lag doesn't really happen because it will be covered up with the "loading screen"

Thanks in advanced!!

Comment: The 'lag' should not happen even in the first place, unless you are doing some cpu-intensive stuff on main thread. Do any long task in a background thread, and present a UIActivityView while it runs.

Comment: Well I think the AudioPlayer that I am running in the "ViewWillAppear" method is actually causing the "lag" so I just solved it by doing
[self performSelector:@selector(function) withObject:self afterDelay:0.5];

This allowed the ViewController to be presented right away with no "lag" and then the View starts the song after the delay

Comment: And in that case, this question should be closed... My bad haha. Thank you for your advice about the UIActivityView

Answer (score 0):

Write this code in your first class eg :-

```
- (IBAction) clickButton:(UIButton *) sender 
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(presentAnotherView) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0f];
    }

    - (void) presentAnotherView
    {
        HomeViewController *home = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];

        [self presentModalViewController:home animated:YES];
    }
```